# Unexpected Syntax Error OOP

Tags: python, class, oop, syntax-error

I am currently working on an assignment for Python involving three classes: Rectangle, Canvas, and Point. I am getting a syntax error when I try setting a second rectangle equal to a already set rectangle:

```
>>> r1 = Rectangle(Point(), Point(1,1), "red")
>>> r2=eval(repr(r1))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    r2=eval(repr(r1))
  File "<string>", line 1
    I am a red rectangle with bottom left corner at (0, 0) and top right corner at (1, 1).
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

this is the function it seems to have a problem with:

```
def __repr__(self):
    return 'I am a '+str(self.color)+' rectangle with bottom left corner at '+str(self.p1.get())+' and top right corner at '+str(self.p2.get())+'.'
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here

Comment: Why are you trying to interpret the `repr()` output as Python code?

Answer (score 0):

Your `__repr__` method works just fine. Where you are going wrong is passing the result to the `eval()` function.

`eval()` takes a string input and executes it as Python code. Your `__repr__` method doesn't return Python code, it returns an English language sentence.

Remove the `eval()` call, you don't need it to show the result of your method. `r2 = repr(r1)` works.

If you are expected to produce a valid Python expression that lets you re-create the object, you need to return such an expression from the `__repr__` method:

```
def __repr__(self):
    return 'Rectangle({!r}, {!r}, {!r})'.format(self.p1, self.p2, self.color)
```

The `!r` tells `str.format()` to take the `repr()` value of the object, so for the `Point` class you'll also need to produce a similar `__repr__` method that returns a string that can recreate those objects.

Comment: I had thought the same thing!! But the line we are speaking of was given to us by the teacher, and it must work using this line, any ideas??

Comment: @MatteoColombi: I have no idea what your teacher is expecting the `__repr__` method to return. Perhaps you need to return something that'll actually can be executed as Python code? E.g., return the string `'Rectangle(Point(), Point(1,1), "red")'`, which would be executable to reproduce the same object again. But I can't see your homework nor see what your teacher has been teaching you.

Comment: I'm not sure either but she gave us the line r2=eval(repr(r1)) and expected it to set r2 equal to r1, but in my function it says there is a syntax error when i put that line into shell